# How to configure klocwork continuous analysis on TFS souce code?

Tags: tfs, klocwork

I have my source code in tfs. We have klocwork analysis server installed and configured. I want to do continuous integration build in tfs to analyse the source code using Klocwork analysis.

Kindly let me know how to create build in tfs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no default steps to trigger a klocwork analysis in a build definition.
I found that klocwork supports command line.

So as a workaround, maybe you could try to add a [Command Line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/command-line) step in your build definition and run [Kwcheck command](https://support.roguewave.com/documentation/klocwork/en/10-x/kwcheck/) in the build definition.